# FileOutputStream is reducing the file size to 0

Tags: java

I have created a file using `RandomAccessFile` with preallocated size. But when I am using `FileOutputStream` to write into the same it is changing the size of the file. Is there any way to stop this using `FileOutputStream`

```
   import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class testFileSize {

      public static class Status implements Serializable {

      }

      public static void preAllocate(String path, long maxSize, boolean preAllocate)
          throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
        try {
          raf.setLength(maxSize);
        } finally {
          raf.close();
        }
      }

      /**
       * @param args
       * @throws IOException 
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = null;
        try {
          final File f = new File("/tmp/test.bin");      
          preBlow(f.getAbsolutePath(), 2048, false);
          Status s = new Status();
          fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
          objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
          objectOutput.writeObject(new Status());
          objectOutput.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          objectOutput.close();
          fileOutput.close();
        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: Hint: read the Javadoc for fileoutputstream and look at the available constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your file is changing size because you're opening the file on create mode, so the previous contents are lost

```
fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Try opening your file in `append` mode, using an extra `boolean` flag while constructing your [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

```
fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I do not want append , is there any way to avoid append

Comment: If I do something like this then it works                                {{{RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), "rw");
      fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(raFile.getFD());}}}